# Reifying groundness in Prolog with Attributed Variables

Tags: prolog, prolog-coroutining

I'm working on my own implementation of [`when/2`](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/mpg_002dref_002dwhen.html).

Internally, `when/2` needs to be able to—for a lack of a better word—"reify" `ground/1`. Doing this using attributed variables (in the style of
SICStus-Prolog) is what this question is all about.

My implementation should work like the following "reference" implementation:

```
ground_t(Term,T) :-
   when(ground(Term), T=true).
```

In a fit of curiosity, I wrote the following little solver:

```
:- module(ground_t,[ground_t/2]).

:- use_module(library(atts)).
:- attribute ground_t/1.

ground_t(Term,T) :-
    (  ground(Term)
    -> T = true
    ;  term_variables(Term,Vs),
       create_mutable(Vs,MVs),
       attach_to_new_vars(Vs,MVs,T)
    ).

attach_to_new_vars([],_,_).
attach_to_new_vars([V|Vs],MVs,T) :-
    (  get_atts(V,+ground_t(Cs0))
    -> Cs = Cs0
    ;  Cs = []
    ),
    put_atts(V,+ground_t([MVs-T|Cs])),
    attach_to_new_vars(Vs,MVs,T).

% simple case: unify w/ground term
cliques_var_goals__ground([],_,[]).
cliques_var_goals__ground([MVs-T|Cs],Var,Goals) :-
    get_mutable(Vs0,MVs),
    list_eq_removed_atmost_once(Vs0,Var,Vs1),
    update_mutable(Vs1,MVs),
    (  Vs1 = []
    -> Goals = [T=true|Goals0]
    ;  Goals = Goals0
    ),
    cliques_var_goals__ground(Cs,Var,Goals0).

list_eq_removed_atmost_once([],_,[]).
list_eq_removed_atmost_once([X|Xs],E,Ys) :-
    (  X == E
    -> Ys = Xs         % remove item. do it at most once and stop
    ;  Ys = [X|Ys0],
       list_eq_removed_atmost_once(Xs,E,Ys0)
    ).

% general case: unify w/non-ground term
cliques_var_other__nonvar([],_,_).
cliques_var_other__nonvar([MVs-T|Cs],Var,Other) :-
    get_mutable(Vs0,MVs),
    term_variables(Vs0+Other,Vs1),
    term_variables(Other,New0),
    list_eq_removed_atmost_once(New0,Var,New),
    list_eq_removed_atmost_once(Vs1,Var,Vs2),
    attach_to_new_vars(New,MVs,T),
    update_mutable(Vs2,MVs),
    cliques_var_other__nonvar(Cs,Var,Other).

sort_all([]).
sort_all([MVs-_T|Xs]) :-
    get_mutable(Vs0,MVs),
    term_variables(Vs0,Vs),
    update_mutable(Vs,MVs),
    sort_all(Xs).

merge_cliques_post_unify(Cs0,Cs1,Other) :-
    append(Cs0,Cs1,Cs01),
    sort_all(Cs01),
    put_atts(Other,+ground_t(Cs01)).

verify_attributes(Var,Other,Goals) :-
    (  get_atts(Var,+ground_t(Cs0))
    -> (  ground(Other)
       -> cliques_var_goals__ground(Cs0,Var,Goals)
       ;  nonvar(Other)
       -> cliques_var_other__nonvar(Cs0,Var,Other),
          Goals = []
       ;  get_atts(Other,+ground_t(Cs1))
       -> Goals = [merge_cliques_post_unify(Cs0,Cs1,Other)]
       ;  put_atts(Other,+ground_t(Cs0)),
          Goals = []
       )
    ;  Goals = []
    ).

cliques_to_goal([]) --> [].
cliques_to_goal([MVs-T|Cs]) -->
    { get_mutable(Vs,MVs) },
    (  { Vs = []  } -> []
    ;  { Vs = [V] } -> [ground_t(V ,T)]
    ;                  [ground_t(Vs,T)]
    ),
    cliques_to_goal(Cs).

list_to_commalist([],true).
list_to_commalist([X],Y) :-
    !,
    X = Y.
list_to_commalist([X|Xs],(X,Y)) :-
    list_to_commalist(Xs,Y).

attribute_goals(Var) -->
    { get_atts(Var,+ground_t(Cs)) },
    cliques_to_goal(Cs).

attribute_goal(Var,Goal) :-
    phrase(attribute_goals(Var),Goals),
    list_to_commalist(Goals,Goal).
```

That was the *easy* part; now comes the *hard* part...

How do I go about testing if the behavior of the two solvers are equivalent—when performing multiple steps of variable aliasing and  instantiation in a forest of shared terms?

---

Here are some simple manual tests that I did:

```
| ?- ground_t(X+Y,T1).
| ?- ground_t(X+Y,T1),X=f(U).
| ?- ground_t(X+Y,T1),X=f(U),U=Y.
| ?- ground_t(X+Y,T1),X=f(U),U=Y,Y=y.
```

```
| ?- ground_t(X+Y,T1),ground_t(X+Z,T2).
| ?- ground_t(X+Y,T1),ground_t(X+Z,T2),X = -U,Z = +V.
| ?- ground_t(X+Y,T1),ground_t(X+Z,T2),X = -U,Z = +U.
| ?- ground_t(X+Y,T1),ground_t(X+Z,T2),X = -U,Z = +U,U=u.
| ?- ground_t(X+Y,T1),ground_t(X+Z,T2),X = -U,Z = +U,U=u,Y=U.
```

Maybe you have a good idea for some nice corner cases... please share!

Comment: Which Prolog system are you using?
For testing, maybe convert both forms to strings (write_canonical or similar) and compare them? Or, it's not difficult to write your own "equivalent" predicate by walking the terms (e.g., use =../2)

Comment: @PeterLudemann: Looks like [SICStus](https://sicstus.sics.se/download_beta.html), at least the prompt is not the prompt of Scryer nor SWI.

Comment: @PeterLudemann. Yes, I'm targeting systems that offer a SICStus-style attributed-variable interface. The two main tricky parts when testing seem to be: (1) getting a "good" representation of the residual goals I can work with, (2) generating a series of successive instantiations that are interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **really** hard part is first of all understanding what `ground_t/2` is actually about. It is not reifying anything, for there is no `false`.

It seems to be some internal auxiliary predicate you need to implement `when/2`. If it is an internal predicate, it does not need to fulfill all the expectations we have about a real constraint.  Most notably, your implementation (as well as your reference implementation using the built-in `when/2`) does not constrain all involved variables:

```
SICStus 4.8.0beta3 (x86_64-linux-glibc2.17): Mon Oct 17 20:11:03 UTC 2022
...
| ?- when(ground(A-B),T=true),copy_term(A,Ac,Ac_0),copy_term(B,Bc,Bc_0).
Ac_0 = prolog:trig_ground(Ac,[_A],[Ac,_A],_B,_B),
Bc_0 = true,
prolog:trig_ground(A,[B],[A,B],_C,_C),
prolog:when(_C,ground(A-B),user:(T=true)) ? ;
no
| ?- ground_t(A-B,T),copy_term(A,Ac,Ac_0),copy_term(B,Bc,Bc_0).
Ac_0 = ground_t:(ground_t([Ac,_A],_B),true),
Bc_0 = ground_t:true ? ;
no
| ?- ground_t(A-B,T).
ground_t([A,B],T) ? ;
no
| ?-
```

So both do not really constrain `B`, although the `ground_t:true` kind of gives us a hint. Also, it seems that the goal `ground_t([A,B],T)` is only displayed when no `copy_term/3` has been used.

Given such lax requirements, `freeze/2` is all you need. No need to delve into atvs at all.

```
myground_t(Term, T) :-
    term_variables(Term, Vs),
    myvars_t(Vs, T).

myvars_t([], true).
myvars_t([V|Vs], T) :-
    freeze(V, myground_t([V|Vs], T)).

| ?- myground_t(A-B,T),copy_term(A,Ac,Ac_0),copy_term(B,Bc,Bc_0).
Ac_0 = prolog:freeze(Ac,user:myground_t([Ac,_A],_B)),
Bc_0 = true,
prolog:freeze(A,user:myground_t([A,B],T)) ? ;
no
```

(A good implementation of [`term_variables/2`](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/dtc2#term_variables) could avoid recreating identical list suffixes. No, there is currently none I know of.)
What is missing in this implementation?

Now to your actual question about testing. Testing coroutines and constraints requires quite a lot of compute. So one may ask in advance whether or not the implementation to be tested has been written in such a manner to avoid certain errors *a priori*.  I did not read your code any further than [`term_variables_set/2`](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/lib_002dterms.html#index-term_005fvariables_005fset_002f2-_0028terms_0029-1) whose second argument depends on the very age of variables which means that it might work for one age and does not work for another one. [It would not be the first](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/issues/issues/118). So testing gets here even more complex.  Why this at all?

Comment: Here I got something curious: `| ?- ground_t(A-B,T), (copy_term(A,Ac,Acc);copy_term(B,Bc,Bcc)).
Acc = ground_t:(ground_t([Ac,_A],_B),true) ? ;
Bcc = ground_t:(ground_t([_A,Bc],_B),true) ? ;
no`

Comment: At least your observation is consistent with: `| ?- ground_t(A-B,T), copy_term(B,Bc,Bc_0).       
Bc_0 = ground_t:(ground_t([_A,Bc],_B),true) ? ;
no`

Comment: So using `term_variables/2` instead of `term_variables_set/2` would be a good move... Very good! (For some reason I believed that sorting the list of variables could help me detect some redundant internal sets.)

Comment: Ad `term_variables/2`: It's in Cor.2 not without reason. There were so many such problems.

Comment: The `ground_t:attribute_goal/2`implementation above is not idempotent, it is supposed to just bind the second argument to the attached goals, but the above implementation also modifies the attached data.  This is why `copy_term/3` (which uses `M:attribute_goal/2`) misbehaves.

Comment: @PerMildner: Please write it as an answer.