# Spurious attribute_goal/2 in SICStus Prolog 4.7.1

Tags: prolog, sicstus-prolog

Given the following minimalistic "solver" in SICStus Prolog ...

```
:- module(attach, [attach/1]).
:- use_module(library(atts)).
:- attribute a/0.

attach(X) :- put_atts(X,a).

verify_attribute(_,_,[]).

attribute_goal(V,attach(V)) :- get_atts(V,a), put_atts(V,-a).
```

... I observe:

```
| ?- attach(X), copy_term(X,Xc,Xcc), copy_term(X,Yc,Ycc).
Xcc = attach:attach(Xc),
Ycc = true ?
```

*Where has the residual goal gone?!*

Wasn't the `put_atts/2` in `attribute_goal/2` *undone*?

---

**Edit.** This [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74640629/4609915) (of a somewhat related question) hints at a similar issues when using the builtin predicate `when/2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the side effects (the `put_atts(V, -a)` that removes the attribute) of your `attribute_goal/2` will not be undone by `copy_term/3` (or `frozen/2` et al.) and I do not think there is anything in the [SICStus documentation](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus/lib_002datts.html) that suggests that it would be.

A simplified version of `copy_term/3`, that only handles variables, would look something like:

```
my_copy_term(Var, Copy, Goal) :-
        (   attribute_goal(Var, VarGoal) ->
            true
        ;   VarGoal = true
        ),
        copy_term(Var-VarGoal, VarCopy-VarGoalCopy),
        Copy = VarCopy,
        Goal = VarGoalCopy.
```

So, if `attribute_goal/2` removes an attribute, like in your example, the attribute will still be absent when (`my_`)`copy_term/3` succeeds.

The effect of `put_atts/2` will be undone on backtracking, as can be seen in the following two examples, where the first is your example, the second is the same but backtracking over the `copy_term/3` before the second `copy_term/`3 is invoked.

```
| ?- attach(X), copy_term(X,Xc,Xcc), copy_term(X,Yc,Ycc).
Xcc = attach:attach(Xc),
Ycc = true ? 
yes
% zip,source_info
| ?- attach(X), (copy_term(X,Xc,Xcc); copy_term(X,Yc,Ycc)).
Xcc = attach:attach(Xc) ? ;
Ycc = attach:attach(Yc) ? ;
no
```

Comment: So this means that `attribute_goal/2` should do whatever it can to remain "pure" lest `copy_term/3` anomalies like the ones above show up?

Comment: Yes, it should just read information from the attribute, not modify the attribute (or the variable).

Comment: Also, it should not alter some *other* shared variables (say, in some kind of coordination effort with other invokations of `attribute_goal/2`).